# VBA dynamic cell range resize

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code and I want to format the `Grand Total` row. I want to make this dynamic because the cells of the grand total row change every month

```
Sub ReportData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Report As Worksheet
Set Report = WBNew.Worksheets("Report")

Report.UsedRange.Copy
With Sheets("Report").UsedRange
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     .Columns("A:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
     Set Rng = .FIND(What:="Grand Total", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
     Rng.Resize(, 18).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

For example if I find "Grand Total" in cell A20, then I want to extent to the last used cell for example X20. But this is my problem it's not always X20 it changes.

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: I want to change Rng.Resize(, 18).Interior.ColorIndex = 20 to dynamic its not always 18 cells it might be 20 or 15 cells from the Grand total cell i find in column A

Comment: So basically, "Grand Total" is the header of a row? You are searching for it and when you find it you want to assign to `rng` all the non-empty cells? In other words, is it the last used cell in the row "Grand Total" which determines the length of the range?

Comment: Yes for example I find grand total to cell A20 and i want to extent to the last use cell for example X20 but this is my problem its not always X20 it change

Comment: Vaggelis in that case you will probably benefit from looking into the .End(xlToRight) property of the range. @SJR you will probably benefit from https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Cells(Rng.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` to find the last used cell in the row where you found `Grand Total` and use that to color the range.

```
Set Rng = .FIND(What:="Grand Total", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Report")
        .Range(Rng, .Cells(Rng.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Grand Total was not found."
End If
```

Note that you need to check `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then` otherwise you will run into an error if `Grand Total` does not exist.

Comment: It worked fine but if i want to go further and i want to delete all the rows below grand total row how to do it ?

Comment: `.Rows(Rng.Row + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete`